# Avoid for-loop in array operation from 1D array of size kN to 1D array of size N

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop

**Input:** I have a 1D `numpy` array of size 3N. Every three elements of the 3N-size array can be denoted as xi, yi, zi where i = 1 ... N.

**Output:** With this array as input, I want to return an output array of size N, that does a `numpy` operation for every three elements (i.e., xi, yi, zi). That means, the value of ith element of the output array is `numpy_operation(xi, yi, zi)`.

**Explaination:** Here is a figure to illustrate the problem:
[image]

Here, the input array has the size of 99 (= 3 x 33). The output array has the size of 33. As an example, I am doing `numpy.argmin(...)` operation for every three elements of the input array.

Is there any trick so that I can avoid for-loop like this?

```
for i in range(len(output_array)):
    output_array[i] = np.argmin(input_array[i * 3 : i * 3 + 3])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reshape and `argmin`:

```
arr.reshape(-1,3).argmin(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape and apply `np.argmin()` on axis=1

```
n = np.random.random((3*100))
out = np.argmin(n.reshape((-1,3)), axis=1)

print(n.shape)
print(out.shape)
```

```
(300,)
(100,)
```